# Python. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, lambda, web-scraping, attributeerror

Why is it this code won't work and give AttributeError?

```
internship = parser.find_all('a', attrs = {'title': lambda job: job.startswith('Internship')})
```

while this one works:

```
internship = parser.find_all('a', attrs = {'title': lambda job: job and job.startswith('Internship')})
```

This is the error that I got from the first code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1299, in find_all
   return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 549, in _find_all
   found = strainer.search(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1690, in search
   found = self.search_tag(markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1662, in search_tag
    if not self._matches(attr_value, match_against):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1722, in _matches
    return match_against(markup)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line of code, you are getting the attribute error because the code assumes that `job` contains a string, which has the method `startswith()`, but it doesn't contain a string, it contains `None`.

In the second line of code, you are not getting the attribute error because the code is testing to see if `job` contains `None`, before calling `startswith()` on it. Another (not quite equivalent but arguably better) way to express

```
lambda job: job and job.startswith('Internship')
```

is

```
lambda job: job.startswith('Internship') if job else False
```

Comment: PEP008 says that that comparisons to `None` should be written `if foo is None`, rather than `if foo`. I realise that the OP's code is also 'incorrect' in this sense, but if making recommendations, it's better to recommend 'compliant' code. IMHO.

Comment: SiHa, I was trying to explain what OP's `and` was doing because he clearly didn't understand that: it was the point of his question. You are of course right, but changing the comparison would have cluttered up the explanation.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, btw, is there any other alternative to the code that you recommend that has the same purpose with that?

Comment: @garjted: No reason not to use SiHa's proposal of `lambda job: job.startswith('Internship') if job is not None else False`. And if you like the explanation please accept it as the answer to your question.